# How to get caption above listing with minted?

Tags: positioning, captions, minted

I'm using the `minted` package. How can I get the caption to show before the code in the document?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
    \begin{listing}[H]
        \caption{This is below the code.}
        \inputminted{matlab}{myfile.m}
        \label{lst:the-code}
    \end{listing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to use the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `floatrow` package will do the trick, but it must be loaded before `minted` to prevent it from loading the `float` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{minted}    
\floatsetup[listing]{style=Plaintop}    
\begin{document}    
    \begin{listing}[H]    
        \caption{This is above the code.}    
        \inputminted{matlab}{myfile.m}    
        \label{lst:the-code}    
    \end{listing}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine, but the output you attached does not match it.

Comment: Impressive that apparently no one (including myself) noticed this for more than four years. That's what happens when answering questions while I should be asleep.

Answer (score 10):

The in January released 2.0 version of minted allows you to use the `newfloat`-package instead of the (rather old) `float`-package.
If you want to use `newfloat`, the method for positioning the caption above the source is not the same as Jonas's but rather the following.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\captionsetup[listing]{position=top}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
    \caption{This is above the code.}
    \inputminted{matlab}{myfile.m}
    \label{lst:the-code}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image: Minted-listing using newfloat]

---

**Important:** you *have to* place the `\caption`-command above your source-code within the `listing`-float.
The `\captionsetup` only applies correct spacing but you have to place the command at the right position yourself.