# How can I use \cref to reference a minted environment?

Tags: minted, cleveref

I've tried

```
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{SQL}
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lineitem
WHERE l_shipdate <= :shipdate
\end{minted}
\label{test}
\end{listing}
```

but it doesn't work. `\cref{test}` reference to the parent section

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something that has a number, i.e. a `\caption`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{SQL}
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lineitem
WHERE l_shipdate <= :shipdate
\end{minted}
\caption{Testing}
\label{test}
\end{listing}
See \cref{test}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! but this looks a bit ugly. Can I have something like a surrounding box with title?

Comment: @Amos You can add a simple frame (or rather, lines above and below) with `\begin{minted}[frame=lines]{SQL}`, but the manual mentions that both the `tcolorbox` and `mdframed` packages  have interfaces for `minted`, so in that sense there is a lot of flexibility with regard to frames. To move the caption to the top, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256796/586

Comment: @Amos If you have any more requirements I suggest you ask a new question about it.