# Change caption setup in listing/minted environment

Tags: captions, listings, minted

I would like to change the appearance of the caption of a code snippet that I have created with minted and listing. However, using `\captionsetup[listing]{<options>}` does not change anything. Does someone know how to change the caption setup in a listing/minted environment so that the caption is closer to the code?

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setminted{frame=single}

\captionsetup[listing]{belowskip=-10pt} % --> is not working

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{listing}[!h]
    \begin{minted}{c}
    int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
    }
    \end{minted}
\caption{test code 2}
\label{code:2}
\end{listing}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use `\usepackage{listing}` and instead `\usepackage[newfloat,chapter]{minted}`, see the answer on the related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256796 for an example.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. It is, however, not possible to load the `newfloat` option as  `\listingscaption` and `\listoflistingscaption` are then undefined and produce an error.

Comment: In that case you might try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261048.

Comment: Perfect, this solution solved my problem. Thanks.